# Array sort C, is it correct?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I wrote this function to order array elements, is it good?

I'm still a noob in C programming, so I prefer to ask.

```
bSortArray(int array[], int arrayL)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<arrayL;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<arrayL-1;j++)
        {
            if(array[i]<array[j])
            {
                temp=array[i];
                array[i]=array[j];
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `j = 0` to `j = i + 1`, `i < arrayL` to `i < arrayL - 1` and `j < arrayL - 1` to `j < arrayL`.

Comment: No, it is not correct. Say, for an array of 10 elements, you will perform comparison and swap for (i = 2, j = 5) pair and later you will perform the same thing for (i = 5, j = 2) pair. Why? There's no "ordering" semantics of any kind in the actions you perform.

Comment: This question seems better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a bubble sort bring small values to the beginning of the array,
or you can have bubble sort bring large values to the end of the array.
The animation on the Wikipedia page shows the 2nd case.
Refer to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Here is an implementation that will terminate the looping early if it does a pass over i without swapping anything.
http://www.c.happycodings.com/Sorting_Searching/code4.html

Note that the inner loop should compare the value at a given index against its' neighbor.
i.e.
array[j] > array[j+1].

Answer (score -1):

Use qsort() - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/

More information provided if need be.

Comment: That's just about as useful as saying `use jQuery` on a java question.

Comment: It's a C function in the standard library.  So not really like saying use a JavaScript framework in Java, which is a different language.

Comment: Yes, it is, but it doesn't help the OP's question. He asked how to fix his algorithm, not how to sort arrays..